# SIP/PyQt5: Overloaded functions with same Python signature

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt, python-sip

SIP/PyQt5 is reporting an error during the parsing of my sip file:

```
__rshift__() has overloaded functions with the same Python signature
```

The offending functions are:

```
QDataStream& operator<<( QDataStream& stream,
                         const Sy_loggerInterface::DebugLevel& obj );
QDataStream& operator>>( QDataStream& stream,
                         Sy_loggerInterface::DebugLevel& obj );

QDataStream& operator<<( QDataStream& stream,
                         const Sy_loggerInterface::RotationMetric& obj );
QDataStream& operator>>( QDataStream& stream,
                         Sy_loggerInterface::RotationMetric& obj );
```

`Sy_loggerInterface::DebugLevel` and `Sy_loggerInterface::RotationMetric` are enums, so they clearly don't have the same signature *in C++*.  But I don't know what the created Python signature would look like.

Also note the left shift operators do not cause an error when I comment out one of the right shift ones, and simply changing the names of the parameters has no effect (as you would expect).  Does anyone know what I can do to fix this error?